# How to retrive the system calls from my Android OS in an external file

Tags: android, file, kernel, system, system-calls

I want for studyng purposes to read the system calls of a specific application in Android OS.  Is there any script or way that i can monitor those calls and get them out in some file ???? I know how to find and get them in a normal linux OS by using the "strace" command, but i want something similiar in an Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strace` command on Android too. The easiest way I can think of is:

1. Root the device
2. Install *BusyBox* (You can use [BusyBox installer from PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox))

This will install `strace` in your device. It may then be used with `adb shell strace` through a computer or in a [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) within the device itself or through code making your own application.